# How to use use PuTTY with RIDE Robot Framework

Tags: linux, putty

I use `Run` keyword of Selenium lib to run `ssh` command from RIDE as follows

```
Run ssh root@ip
```

Now my command starts with `putty`. When I use following from RIDE

```
Run putty root@ip
```

It says

> putty is not internal or external command

Does anyone know how to sort it out, I need to connect using PuTTY in this case.

Comment: ive some doubt and its because i dont know selenium, but did you asking to you how linux will handle to run win32 aplications?,

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the command from the folder PuTTY is installed in, provide the full path, or add PuTTY's install location to your path variable.